# SDR /search mapping collision

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I'm using Spring Data REST with Spring Boot 1.5.4 and I have a trouble.

I defined repository:

```
public interface TicketRepository extends JpaRepository<Ticket, Long> {

    @RestResource(path = "find-by-ticket-list-id")
    Page<Ticket> findByTicketListIdOrderByPosition(@Param("ticketListId") Long ticketListId, Pageable pageable);
}
```

I need a specific GET method. So I defined the controller:

```
@RepositoryRestController
public class TicketController {

    @GetMapping("/tickets/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getTicket(@PathVariable Long id, PersistentEntityResourceAssembler assembler) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And now, when I try to get a list of search resources, I get an error

> Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
>   'java.lang.Long'

I understand that this is due to a collision of `/tickets/{id}` and `/tickets/search`, but I do not understand how to deal with this. I tried to put `@Order` before the `getTicket` method and before `TicketController` definition, but it did not change anything.

How to resolve both URI's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Regular Expressions in URI Template Patterns:

```
@GetMapping("/tickets/{id:\\d+}")
public ResponseEntity<?> getTicket(@PathVariable Long id, PersistentEntityResourceAssembler assembler) {
    ...
}
```

[More info](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates-regex)...